# Return from static initializer

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning in a static initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607112/returning-in-a-static-initializer)

Is there a way to exit a static initialiser in Java, something like the code below (which does not compile):

```
public class Test {

    private static int i = 1;

    static {
        if (i == 0) {
            return; // DOESN'T COMPILE
        }
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

ps: yes I know, the example makes no sense, `i == 0` will always be false at this point, but that's not the point!

Comment: Use `System.exit(0)` instead.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I don't want to exit, just continue to the rest of the code - the duplicate answers why it is not possible, thanks.

Comment: OK then, use a label on an instance block and break that label. `static{label:{if(i == 0) break label; i = 0}}`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That's an ugly hack, but it does work indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty method would be, misusing a `for` loop and use its `break` statement for flow control:

```
static
{
    int i = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            break;
        // more code
        // more conditions
        // don't forget the final break
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a label is cleaner :) .. I want to +1 this answer, but I'm running out of up-votes for the rest of the day :)

Comment: :-) That's why I said quick and dirty^^