# Can i put a empty return statement inside an instance initializer?

Tags: java, initializer

I'm am trying to put a empty return statement inside an instance initializer block to exit in case the string is null but compiler say "Cannot return from within an initializer" , i have found this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607112/returning-in-a-static-initializer) on stack-overflow but it's about "**static initializer**" and maybe my case is different, this is the code:

```
lsDestinatari.parallelStream().forEach(o->{
    pushManagerDB.insert("log_notifiche",new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
        String logContent = pushToPlayers(getPlayersFromUser(o,pushManagerDB),content,data,page);
        if(logContent==null)
            return;     
        put("content", logContent);
        //TODO[...]     
    }});
});
```

Comment: No, you can't, just like the compiler tells you. Simple workaround is, don't use a return.

Comment: @pvg i'm looking for a different workaround ..

Comment: @MikeD3ViDTyson there is no workaround other than not using `return`, or not using an initializer. It is an error by specification. So, *why* are you looking for a different workaround, and what do you think that different workaround would look like?

Comment: @MikeD3ViDTyson that's great but it's not really an answerable specific question any more than 'I still haven't found what I'm looking for' is. What are we supposed to tell you, to look where the streets have no name?

Comment: looks that's similar question and the people do not complain the author ...  :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607112/returning-in-a-static-initializer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MikeD3ViDTyson that's because that poster is asking a specific question. You're saying you don't like the JLS, which is not really a question. The spec says 'you can't use return' and you say 'But I wanna'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `return` in an initializer: as it says in [JLS Sec 8.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6):

> It is a compile-time error if a return statement (§14.17) appears anywhere within an instance initializer.

In this case, you don't need to: just `put` only in the non-null case:

```
if (logContent != null) {
  put("content", logContent);
}
```

---

But note that there's no need to be using an initializer at all. I know that some people think that double-brace initialization is a smart trick; but honestly, it's more trouble than it's worth. You create unnecessary subclasses, potentially enclose references which lead to memory leaks, break serialization etc. All for the sake of "saving" a few lines of code.

Just build the map outside the insert call:

```
String logContent = pushToPlayers(getPlayersFromUser(o,pushManagerDB),content,data,page);
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
if (logContent != null) {
  map.put("content", logContent);
}
pushManagerDB.insert("log_notifiche", map);
```

or

```
pushManagerDB.insert(
    "log_notifiche",
    logContent != null
        ? Collections.singletonMap("content", logContent)
        : Collections.emptyMap());
```

Comment: @MikeD3ViDTyson no. If you need to use `return`, you're probably trying to do too much in the initializer.

Comment: Word of advice, @Mike, don't be so quick to believe the compiler when it says you can't do something; it's only right about 99.999999...99% of the time (;->) .

Comment: @AndyTurner OK , the ternary op is quite cute. i will opt for that , that's a honor to speak with a google engineer (i'm serious) thank you!

Comment: @KevinAnderson ٩(- ̮̮̃-̃)۶